# Why does the colorbar do not appear in my cloropleth map?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

I have plotted a cloropleth map. But the colorbar bar does not appear properly.

This is the dataframe I am using:

[image]

This is my code:

```
ax=new_df.plot(figsize=(18,16), column='count', cmap='Blues', k=5, legend=True)
plt.title("Number of IPs by district - Ontario")
ax.set_axis_off()
```

This is what I have:

[image]

Comment: Look at `new_df.dtypes`. Your `'count'` column is probably an Object column of strings. Convert them to numeric. The colors are correct because strings can still be sorted, but making a continuous legend doesn't make sense the way it would for a numeric type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the column 'count' was of type Object. So, after converting it to numeric, it was possible to plot the colorbar as well as the cloropleth map.

[image]

```
#Converting to numeric
new_df['count'] = new_df['count'].astype('int16')
new_df.dtypes

#Plotting
ax=new_df.plot(figsize=(12,12), column='count', cmap='Blues', k=5, legend=True)
plt.title("Number of IPs by district - Ontario")
ax.set_axis_off()
```

[image]